# VBA Type mismatch for multiple sub-loops and a long range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, nested-loops

Fairly new to VBA here, but have managed put together this script that loops through a number of sheets, completing a sumif function along the way - which is stored and then printed following each loop. There are 65 sheets and some may be added in the future, so I have listed each tab name in a named Table ("tab_ref[Tab]"), and use this as the reference for the loop.

I'm running into a really strange error. When I set the sheetrange as ONLY the first 4 sheets listed in the table ("H15:H18") the function works perfectly, however when I try to loop through the full range (or even just one more - "H15:H19"!) I get a Type mismatch error further down the code. Can anyone see what is causing this error? A fix or any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub ClusterLevel()

Dim inputcell As Range, itemrange As Range, sheetrange As Range, _
FullRow As Range, Items As Range, CalcRange As Range, printCalc As Range

Set inputcell = Sheets("Calculations").Range("C10")
Set itemrange = Sheets("Calculations").Range("A21:A22")
Set sheetrange = Sheets("Reference Sheet").Range("H15:H19") 'Sheets listed here. "H15:H18" WORKS - BUT "tab_ref[Tab]" DOESN'T!!

i = 21

For Each entry In itemrange
sumState = 0

For Each sheet In sheetrange
    Set FullRow = Sheets(sheet.Value).Range("A5:EE5")
    Set Items = Sheets(sheet.Value).Range("A6:A500")

    For Each Cell In FullRow
        If Cell.Value = inputcell.Value Then 'TYPE MISMATCH HERE
            With FullRow
            Set SumRange = Range(.Cells(Cell.Row - 3, Cell.Column), .Cells(520, Cell.Column))
            sumState = sumState + WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Items, entry, SumRange)
            End With
        End If
    Next Cell
Next sheet

Set printCalc = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(i, 4)
printCalc = sumState
i = i + 1
Next entry

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value in H19 ?

Comment: Just the name of the next tab. Initially thought it might have been a spelling error, but the list names each tab correctly. H19 is "HACCMV"

Comment: At which line do you exactly get the error (press "debug" look the error message)?

Comment: I think I've worked out the issue, but not sure how to solve. The column heading we are looking for isn't present in that sheet. I.e. inputCell.Value is not in this sheet. Is there a way I can build in a "if not found, move to next sheet"?

Comment: I don't understand how that works at all. The `Cell.Row - 3` in one of the loops means that the size of `SumRange` will change with every pass. However, the `Items` range does not change size. A [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) must have identically sized criteria_range and sum_range. That line would be better as `Set SumRange = .Cells(Cell.Row - 3, Cell.Column).Resize(Items.Rows.count, 1)`

Comment: Nope, this isn't the issue. Back to square one!

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped - Yes, it took me a while to get the sumif to work how it is - slightly confusing! Thanks for the improvement. Still getting the type mismatch however.

Comment: Have you checked the `Cell` for `#N/A`, `#DIV/0!`, `#VALUE!` etc errors?

Comment: @Jeeped - This is EXACTLY what was wrong! Fixed by adding CStr() to both Cell.Value and inputcell.Value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following modifications to your primary worksheet loop.

```
For Each Sheet In sheetrange
    On Error GoTo bm_NoSheet
    Set FullRow = Sheets(Sheet.Value).Range("A5:EE5")
    Set Items = Sheets(Sheet.Value).Range("A6:A500")
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each Cell In FullRow
        If Cell.Value = inputcell.Value Then 'TYPE MISMATCH HERE
            With FullRow
            Set SumRange = Range(.Cells(Cell.Row - 3, Cell.Column), .Cells(520, Cell.Column))
            sumState = sumState + WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Items, entry, SumRange)
            End With
        End If
    Next Cell
    GoTo bm_Next
bm_NoSheet:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        With Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            .Name = Sheet.Value
        End With
        Resume
    End If
bm_Next:
Next Sheet
```

This will create a worksheet if it cannot be found. I am still unclear on what line is generating the error but this is my best guess. If a new worksheet is created at the end of the worksheet queue then you need to examine the worksheet names you have stored closely. If not, please supply the actual line of code that is generating the error.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. Sorry, the line generating the error is "If Cell.Value = inputcell.Value Then" within the Cell In Full Row loop

Answer (score 0):

The cells in FullRow were created with a vlookup on each tab, and some were returning N/A. This was throwing the error when referenced.

Easy fix by converting to string as such:
`If CStr(Cell.Value) = CStr(inputcell.Value Then)`

Thanks for the help all!